# ActiveSlick query compilation error

Tags: scala, slick

What is wrong with this ActiveSlick query?

```
import io.strongtyped.active.slick.ActiveSlick
import io.strongtyped.active.slick.models.Identifiable

import scala.slick.driver._
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile._

trait MappingActiveSlickIdentifiable {
  this: ActiveSlick =>

  import jdbcDriver.simple._

  case class Foo(name: String, id: Option[Int] = None) extends Identifiable[Foo] {
    override type Id = Int
    override def withId(id: Id): Foo = copy(id = Some(id))
  }
  class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends EntityTable[Foo](tag, "FOOS") {
    def name = column[String]("NAME")
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def * = (name, id.?) <> (Foo.tupled, Foo.unapply)
  }
  val Foos = new EntityTableQuery[Foo, FooTable](tag => new FooTable(tag))
}

object MappingActiveSlickIdentifiable {

  class Components(override val jdbcDriver: JdbcDriver)
    extends ActiveSlick
    with MappingActiveSlickIdentifiable {
    import jdbcDriver.simple._
    val db = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:active-slick", driver = "org.h2.Driver")
    def createSchema(implicit s:Session): Unit = {
      Foos.ddl.create
    }
  }

  object Components {
    val instance = new Components(H2Driver)
  }

  import Components.instance._

  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {

    db.withTransaction { implicit s =>

      createSchema

      (1 to 3) foreach { i =>
        val foo = Foo(s"foo $i")
        val fooWithId : Foo = Foos.save(foo)
        Foos.update(fooWithId.copy(name = "?"))
        println(s"Foo: $foo, foo with id: $fooWithId")
        assert(fooWithId.id.isDefined, "Foo's ID should be defined")
      }

      val q = for {
        f <- Foos if f.name === "?"
      } yield f.name
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

```
[error] /Volumes/Home/s/hello/slick-active/hw.scala:57: value === is not a member of scala.slick.lifted.Column[String]
[error]         f <- Foos if f.name === "?"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** import there

```
import scala.slick.driver._
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile._
```

import from a particular driver instead, e.g.

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver._
```